# VueJs use attribute value to get array value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In a form, I would like to get the name attribute value to find error message, I wrote manually the name on the errors messages array and it works.

But I would like to not have to write the input name each time.

Exemple :

```html
    <v-container>
         <v-row>
             <v-col cols="12">
                  <v-text-field v-model="label" name="label" :error-messages="errors[NAME_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE]" label="Label" @change="resetFormInputValidation" required></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-row>
              <v-col cols="9">
                   <v-text-field v-model="mimeType" name="mime_type" :error-messages="errors['mime_type']" label="MIME Type" required></v-text-field>
              </v-col>

              <v-col cols="3">
                   <v-text-field v-model="extension" name="file_extension" :error-messages="errors['file_extension']" label="Extension" required></v-text-field>
               </v-col>
           </v-row>
    </v-container>
```

Comment: Since the `name` attribute isn't dynamic, can't you simply use `errors['label']`?

Comment: Yes and it's works, but i have a bigger form and i asked myself if it is possible to get the value directly from the name attribute

Comment: If that's the case then you need to store the name somewhere, like in an array, and then use `v-for` to iterate through the list of names. Then you can use `v-bind` for the name attribute and access it from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can access the name attribute in that way. To further elabourate my comment, a way will be to declare an array containing all the values for the `name` attribute, and then iterating through them using `v-for`. This gives you access to the dynamic name attribute. A proof-of-concept code:

**JS:**

```
data: function() {
    return {
        names: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
    };
}
```

**Template:**

```
<v-container v-for="(name, i) in names" :key="i">
    <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
            <v-text-field v-model="label" :name="name" :error-messages="errors[name]" label="Label" @change="resetFormInputValidation" required></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <!-- Other markup -->
</v-container>
```